In ansible awx how to separate db from the docker container
In ansible awx by default database is running in the container, i do not want to run the db in the docker container, i want to use external db connection. I tried connecting to external db, it is connected and working. When I removed the database related in docker file i got no issues. But when i tried executing the Job Template my Application is getting crashed.
